# SVN - how to commit with issue key

Tags: svn

I host my project on google code and use tortoiseSVN to checkout/update/commit

Go to google code -> project , and create a issue with id: test-1

And every time i commit i have to input this id into message commit

It means every committing need a issue id. If no issue id, no commit

How to do ?

Comment: Linking it to issues is easy, but AFAIK you can't _enforce_ it, nothing in the docs about pre-commit hooks et al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseSVN has bug tracking integration - http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html .

There is also [Gurtle](http://code.google.com/p/gurtle/) which is a TortoiseSVN issue tracker plug-in for Google Code projects.